# Reduce 'oversampling' when using bootstrapping

Tags: resampling, survey-weights

I'm wanting to use bootstrapping to estimate the sampling distribution of values over a geographical area. However, the samples I'm using are more heavily sampled in some areas that in others, for example,

```
__________________________
| x x             xx     |
| x x              x     | 
|          x             |
|                        | 
|     x             x    |
|________________________|
```

If I'm estimating a single value to represent the entire area, it's likely that through re-sampling I'll end up with a value that is more representative of an area of oversampling purely because there are more in a close proximity. However, since I don't have 'lots' of samples I also don't want to just disregard them - should I be applying weights to certain areas to account for this- and what would be the recommended way to approach what weights to apply? - the only way I can think is to grid up the area and divide by the number of samples in each grid.

Comment: // cannot add comment because of reputation so answering :) /// One clarification - One sample per geography seems odd. If it is exactly what you are trying to do then I would suggest take 'Mode' instead of using any sampling. In a nutshell you are trying representing the population using one number by resampling (sampling multiple times to get most common). Please correct me if I have understood your question incorrectly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really follow how and why would you want to use bootstrap in here, or how would it help, but this is a clear case for using [survey-weights](/questions/tagged/survey-weights) (see other questions tagged like this for more details).

For example, if you know that values from some are were sampled three times more often then they appear in reality, you would weight them by 1/3 weight. Such weights can be used for calculating weighed means, but also can be used in many statistical models, e.g. regression, but also in machine learning, where you would just used weighted loss function.